# ClickTag banner issues in Flash CS5

Tags: actionscript-2, flash-cs5, clicktag

I've created some animated as well as static banners in Flash CS5 and I'd like to apply clickTag ActionScript 2.0 code to them. However, I only found tutorials where over all the existing layers, you create a rectangle using the Rectangle Primitive Tool, set the border, fill, and opacity to 0 and then apply the code and export the movie. When I create the rectangle, there is no setting for opacity, and when I set no border and no fill, the rectangle disappears and the dark dot in the timeline becomes empty so I can't click on the rectangle in order to convert it into a symbol.

I would really appreciate any advice on this!

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your rectangle using 'Rectangle Primitive' tool shapes menu instead of the regular Rectangle tool.
2. select your rectangle by a single click.
3. From the properties panel select the bucket symbol (the one used to control the fill color) and you will find a setting 'alpha' for setting the transparency.
4. change the alpha value to 0. after that remove the stroke.
5. select your rectangle, from the top menu : Modify > Convert to symbol. give it a name and select 'button' from the dropdown. press ok.
6. now select the button you just created, open the actions panel and paste the following code :

   on (release) {
       if (clickTAG.substr(0, 5) == "http:")
       {
           getURL(clickTAG, "_blank");
       }
   }